# Installing Pear, what did I do by entering these commands on my terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, pear

I'm trying to figure out how to install Pear on my Mac (10.6.6).

Not understanding what they're telling me at pear.php.net, I got some code from http://clickontyler.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pear-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

First, I entered `curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear > go-pear.php` in my terminal.

It resulted in this output

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 88004  100 88004    0     0  47537      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 59744
```

What does that all mean? Am I on the right track?

Next, I entered  `sudo php -q go-pear.php`

and it gave me the long output below. In short I have no idea where I am in the installation process. However, I'm pretty sure that I'm not where I'm supposed to be at following the tutorial at http://clickontyler.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pear-in-mac-os-x-leopard/
because the tutorial tells me to select all the default choices, and I don't see any options to select.

**The next line of code is asking me to modify the php.ini files and it requires a password so I'm worried about doing it...Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track?**

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini


Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run interactively
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -s               Output HTML syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

Answer (score 0):

`php` does not have an argument `-q`. Its also mentioned in `go-pear.php` (http://pear.php.net/go-pear) itself, but I dont know, what it wants to tell me. However, try

```
sudo php go-pear.php
```

and then follow the instructions.

Update:

`-q` was used, to start the interpreter in "quiet" mode. It seems, that this option does not exists anymore, because php always starts "quiet", but it should not cause an error, anyway. Now make sure you are in the same directory as the file `go-pear.php` before you call `php go-pear.php`.

Comment: I tried sudo php go-pear.php and it said "Sorry!  Your PHP version is too new (5.3.3) for this go-pear.
Instead use http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar for a more stable and current
version of go-pear, more suited to your PHP version." so I did curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar  and it seemed to run all sorts of code called Structured Graph...but now I'm lost. any idea? Was I supposed to put "curl" in front of that URL?

Comment: `curl pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.phar` to download the file, than again `sudo php go-pear.phar`. The only thing you are doing here is to download (via `curl`) and execute (as `sudo` via the `php` interpreter) the installer.

Comment: after I did "sudo php go-pear.phar" it asked me for my password, which I entered, but then it output "????Michael-Mitchells-MacBook-Pro:~ michaelmitchell$"  when I did sudo go-pear.phar again it gave me the same output without asking for the password. any ideas? thanks for your help.

Comment: Note, I found a blog that addresses this ????? garbage output and provides  workaround, but I don't understand exactly what it's saying in terms of what I should do. Any help? http://technosophos.com/content/php-phar-command-line-errors-os-x-running-php-somephar-generates

Answer (score 0):

The first part shows that you successfully downloaded the file to go-pear.php.
The second part is showing that -q isn't a valid option. The third part is asking for the root password, since you're doing 'sudo'.

I used this, though I wasn't installing on Mac:
[Getting and installing the PEAR package manager](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)

Comment: thanks, I looked at the Pear package manager but it didn't make sense to me. I tried it's first command c:\php\go-pear.bat. and my Terminal said "command not found."  I'm very inexperienced with command line stuff.

Comment: "The second part is showing that -q isn't a valid option." Thats not true at all. Its not supported anymore, that true, but now its silently ignored and doesnt cause any further problems.

Comment: You're installing on Mac OS right? The c:\\...bat is for Windows.
In the Mac section:

$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

$ php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar

Comment: KC: If the -q is a valid option, then what caused the 'Usage'?